# How do I hide an app icon in the indicator plugin for xfce4 while keeping the network indicator?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

Distribution: Mint

Picture of the icon I want to get rid of (the problem).

[image: indicator icons]

I have restarted the computer, logged off then in, restarted the panel with `xfce4-panel --restart`.

When I go into the properties page with right clicking the indicator plugin, I get the following while app is active.

[image: indicator properties]

I have tried enable the option "Hide indicators by default", however it also hides the network icon located to the right of the app icon.

Is there any way to hide individual app icons in the indicator plugin?